# Cannot compile after using RNCryptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rncryptor

I am using RNCryptor from [here](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor). but cannot seem to get my app to compile correctly. I get the following errors in the log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNDecryptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EncryptionTransformer.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNEncryptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EncryptionTransformer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: have you resolved this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you built RNCryptor for ARM but you're building your application to run on the Simulator (i386).